# react native app crashes at Geolocation.getCurrentPosition in iOS 16.1

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

The app we have been developing has been working without problems, until iOS 16.1 was installed (on iPhone 11).  We have also encountered this problem on iPhone 14, version 16.0.2.  Updating to iOS 16.3 does fix the problem -- however we have a mandate to work on whatever iOS version the user is running -- since this is a app to  be used in emergency situations, and the user won't have time to update.  So we are looking for programmatic solutions or workarounds -- if that is not possible, settings users can change on their devices that will be quick.  The geolocation library we are using *is react-native-geolocation/community*.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

**work for me**

//  install this -->

npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save

```
if (Geolocation) {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(`Latitude: ${latitude}, Longitude: ${longitude}`);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
  );
} else {
  console.log('Geolocation is not supported on this device');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  What did you change from the code you were running before you installed 16.1?

Comment: plz up my ans..

Comment: change version ..

Comment: What did you change the version of?